# How to Preload images using dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I want to preload some images and delete them later. I had looked some tutorials but it seems not working. My php side is correct, and in order to troubleshoot, I quoted my filename and size directly. Still nothing happened.

Please help me if you know about this. Thanks!

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone  = {

init: function() {
// var thisDropzone = this;

$.get(getPic_url, function(data) {
     $.each(data, function(key,value){ //loop through it

        var mockFile = { name: 'surf-1477342168.jpg', size: 5398538 };    // here we get the file name and size as response 
        Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);

// thisDropzone.options.addedfile.call(thisDropzone, mockFile);
// thisDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(thisDropzone, mockFile, "__UPLOAD__/surf-1477342168.jpg");
    });
});
},
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var mockFile = { name: 'surf-1477342168.jpg', size: 5398538 };

// Call the default addedfile event handler
thisDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);

// And optionally show the thumbnail of the file:
thisDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, "__UPLOAD__/surf-1477342168.jpg");
},
```